# confusion about the suffix 'ence' and "ance"

Tags: etymology, suffixes, syllables

I am confused about using the suffixes "ance" and "ence". Where would I use "ance" and where "ence"? Is there some important rule about this?

Comment: I think this would be better suited for our sister site, English Language Learners.  If you are a native speaker, consider making this question more robust by adding examples of what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

The rule is, when your spelling checker underlines a word ending with **-ance** in red, try **-ence**. ;-)

There's no easy to remember rule. The words are typically derived from Latin words ending **-antia** and **-entia**. Though as English spelling was standardized somewhat inconsistently, even that's not an especially good guide for English.

Comment: In AE, both suffixes are acceptable in "ambiance".